# How to handle a consumer exception as an ack?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to implement exponential backoff for consumer failures. To that end I have three queues with DLX thus: `RETRY -> MAIN -> FAILED`.

Anything rejected from `MAIN` goes `FAILED`, and anything added to `RETRY` goes into `MAIN` after a per-message TTL. The consumer receives from `MAIN`.

I've implemented an `ErrorHandler` and set it on the `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`. This handler either computes a new TTL and sends the message to the `RETRY` queue, or throws `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` if that's not possible or retries are exceeded in order to DLX it to `FAILED`. The problem is, I cannot work out how to get rid of the original message.

As far as I can see I have to ack it, but the `Channel` is not available in the error handler, and there are no other exceptions to throw that would trigger an ack.

If instead I remove the `MAIN -> FAILED` DLX and switch to manually adding messages to `FAILED`, then if that doesn't work I've lost the message.

```
@Override
public void handleError(Throwable t) {
  log.warn("Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.", t);

  try {
    queueForExponentialRetry(((ListenerExecutionFailedException) t).getFailedMessage());
    // what to do here?
  } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    t.addSuppressed(ex);
    log.error("Not requeueing after failure", t);
    throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(t);
  }
  // or here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I immediately found the answer. Missed it before because I was throwing from the the wrong place.

```
@Override
public void handleError(Throwable t) {
  log.warn("Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.", t);

  try {
    queueForExponentialRetry(((ListenerExecutionFailedException) t).getFailedMessage());
  } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    t.addSuppressed(ex);
    log.error("Not requeueing after failure", t);
    throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(t);
  }

  throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("Queued for retry");
}
```

> **ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException**
>
> Special exception for listener implementations that want to signal that the current batch of messages should be acknowledged immediately (i.e. as soon as possible) without rollback, and without consuming any more messages within the current transaction.

This should be safe as I'm not using batches or transactions, only publisher returns.

---

Side note: I should also be aware that exponential backoff isn't going to actually work properly:

> While consumers never see expired messages, only when expired messages reach the head of a queue will they actually be discarded (or dead-lettered). When setting a per-queue TTL this is not a problem, since expired messages are always at the head of the queue. When setting per-message TTL however, expired messages can queue up behind non-expired ones until the latter are consumed or expired.